# БД Oracle для обучения

Tags: oracle

Хочу хоть немного изучить БД Oracle.

1. Где можно скачать БД для обучения? Хотя бы чтобы создать 1 БД и работать с ней.
2. Посоветуйте кроме документации книгу или сайт как работать с Oracle
3. Что такое архивлоги Oracle?

Comment: 1 - Oracle.com. 2 - sql-ex.ru

Comment: В учебных целях вы можете использовать любую версию. Всё доступно для скачивания на оф. сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/ru/database/express-edition/overview/index.html) - бесплатная версия СУБД Oracle
2. [Официальная документация](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/ru/database/express-edition/documentation/index.html)
3. Архивлоги (ARCHIVELOG):

> When you run a database in ARCHIVELOG mode, you enable the archiving of the redo log. The database control file indicates that a group of filled redo log files cannot be reused by LGWR until the group is archived. A filled group becomes available for archiving immediately after a redo log switch occurs.

Грубо говоря, когда БД работает в режиме архивлогов, то есть возможность отката изменений.

Comment: "redo" это не "undo", в первую очередь архивлоги используются для восстановления БД путем наката всех изменений вперед по сохраненным архивлогам на старую полную копию БД. откат на определенное время (flashback) делается по другим логам